# Как ограничить раздачу wi-fi по времени?

Tags: роутер, wifi

Поступила задачка. Есть роутер Zyxel Keenetic Giga + фемтосота (билайн over интернет), wi-fi раздается через тарелки Ubiquiti. Хозяин дома пожелал, чтобы было две сети wi-fi - его и вторая. Вторая должна ограничиваться по времени, например доступ с 8 утра до 23 вечера и ни граммом больше.
Вот смотрю на свой Asus RT-AC66U и вижу в нем "родительский контроль", но не понимаю, каким образом можно наворотить вышеназванное. Прошу помощи!

Answer (score 1):

Информации недостаточно. Общее впечатление - возможностей железа не хватит на такое.

Я помню, что у кинетиков второй версии прошивки была возможность второй гостевой сети (может быть и с доступностью по времени), но это на самом роутере, а не тарелках трансляторах.

Если тарелки в принципе умеют управляться с двумя сетями, то моэжно хотя бы начинать экспериментировать, иначе придётся покупать второй комплект тарелок и вешать их на отдельную сеть.

Первая идея, которая пришла - взять умный роутер. Любой микротик, начиная с 
https://market.yandex.ru/product/12358922?hid=723087
Есть возможность запускать скрипты по планировщику и вообще куча умных особенностей

http://www.technotrade.com.ua/Articles/how_to_limit_throughput_mikrotik.php
вот пример тонкой настройки поведения, есть и по времени.

мой личный совет - микротик

Альтернативные варианты:
поднять Radius авторизацию. Все зарегистрированные домашние гаджеты не ограничиваются в правах, соответственно все остальные попадают под ограничения автоматически.

запустить на сервере в шедулере/кроне задачу "послать команду точке на включение/отключение", по которой каким-то образом на терелки/роутер посылается команда на отключение.

Назначить всем домашним устройствам привязку к адресам по вифи (динамически DHCP будет выдавать один и тот же адрес), соответственно получается два диапазона ип адресов, к которым можно применять правила. Не уверен, что кинетик умеет такие хитрые правила разруливать.

Выпускать в инет через полноценный сервер, а там каким-нибудь траффик инспектором прописать все необходимые правила.

Comment: Алексей, спасибо за столь подробный комментарий. Тарелки можно поменять. Сам склоняюсь к микротику, благо один лежит без дела.